# Deleting a ' from a cell which is not being retrieved in .Value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to find out how to delete a ' which is at the very beginning of every cell in the A column in a Excel but I can't figure out how to do it.

[image]

If I perform a Replace with

```
Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN").Cells(2, 1).Value, "'", "")
```

or just showing the cell value with a MsgBox it just shows the number itself, without the '.

Any idea about how to delete that character if I couldn't even access it?

P.S: I've tried a basic "find and replace" with same result, even saying I have no matches...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Pressing F2 on the "A2" cell to see the formula shows this:
[image]

Comment: is it in the values ? or coming from the `Formula` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado looks like it's inside the Formula

Comment: so you need to remove this "bonus" `'` from your formula

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes, that's it! If I try to get it with a .Value I'm not able to do it, even with a Cell.Formula Replace

Comment: Can you edit your post and share the formula you have in Cell "A2" ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Screenshot done! I just press F2 on it and looks like it's showing the damn '  Thanks BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not see `'` in VBA, neither can you remove it with Excel replace dialog – this is a special symbol that forces numeric values to be treated as text.

You can just reassign formulas and this will remove `'`:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN").Range("A1").Formula = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN").Range("A1").Formula
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I get I was trying to modify a value when I should really modify the formula!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        cell.Value = Val(cell.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Quite funny accessing this! I love this community! <3